# Can I see my own self-deleted posts in the delete votes tab only if I have 10k+ reputation?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, self-delete, votes-tab

For users who have [privilege to see deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (=10k+ on graduated sites), it is easy to find their own deleted posts simply by [searching for deleted:1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1). For users with lower reputation, there is possibility to see those deleted posts that were created in the past 60 days. More details can be found here: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645).

However, every user has also votes tab in their profile, and it is possible to [choose just deletion votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=deletion) there.

I have checked that on a site where I am over 10k I was able to see my own self-deleted post there.

**Question.** If a user who does not have privilege to see deleted posts yet, do they see their own *self-deleted* questions/answers there? If not, are at least the recent ones displayed there (i.e., the self-deleted post which can be found using "deleted recent questions" and "deleted recent answers")?

EDIT: I have now deleted this question - and waited some time before undeleting. While it was deleted, it was not diplayed in my profile in my profile [among delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=deletion). (I can see it there now - after undeletion.) So the answer is probably no - unless I missed something else which could influence whether or not the deleted post is displayed there.

Probably it might still be useful to have this documented somewhere.